# How to Create an Extension for SSMS 2019 (v18)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-extensions, ssms-addin, ssms-18

[SQL Server Management Studio 18 RC1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) became available March 28, 2018

This question has already been asked [for SSMS 17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47240020/1366033), but there are slight variations when authoring extensions for different releases of SQL Server Management Studio.

**What are the steps to getting a Hello World application up an running in SSMS 2019?**

Comment: A more detailed one is also on bounty here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953463/extending-a-code-completion-completionsourceprovider-for-sql-server-management

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here are the complete steps, adapted from Stefan Timovski's article on [How to Create SQL Server Management Studio 18 (SSMS) Extension](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1377559/How-to-Create-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-18-SSMS)

1. **Install [Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) with *Extensions Toolkit***

   If you're not sure you have the extensions toolkit, you can open the Visual Studio Installer and modify your current install to make sure you have extensions installed

   [image: Visual Studio Installer]
   [image: Visual Studio Extension Development]
2. **Create New Extension Project**

   Go to File New Project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)

   [image: File > New > Project]

   Choose Extensibility > VIX Project

   [image: Extensibility > VSIX Project]

   If you don't have these options, go make sure you did step 1
3. **Add a New Command Item**

   Add a new item (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)

   [image: Add New Item]

   Select Extensibility and just for demo purposes grab a custom command

   [image: Extensibility > Custom Command]
4. **Debug in Visual Studio**

   The command file will add a menu item to Tools > Invoke *Command1*. If you hit debug, Visual Studio will launch a Debuggable instance, fully loaded with your current extension.  Hit play or hit <kbd>F5</kbd>

   The first time may take a minute to boot-up, but it should go faster thereafter

   [image: Launch Debug]

   The click event handled in located in *Command1*.cs > `Execute`, and you can add breakpoints.

   [image: Debugger Breakpoint]

   Here's the working message box

   [image: Callback]
5. **Get filepath for SSMS**

   The default installation path for SSMS 18 should be:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
   ```

   If it's not there, to identify the startup location of any app, you can <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Clicking on the app icon and select "Open file location"

   [image: SSMS Location]
6. **Set Launch to SSMS**

   Open up the project properties in VS (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

   [image: Project Properties]

   Go to **Debug** > **Start External Program** and paste in the path

   [image: Debug > Start External Program]

   Remove the command line args as they're no longer applicable to SSMS
7. **Set Deploy VSIX to SSMS**

   The "Extensions" subdirectory should be in the same directory as SSMS. Also, add an extra folder with your project name like this

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Extensions\VSIXProject1
   ```

   Go to **VSIX** > and select "**Copy VSIX content to the following location**"

   [image: VSIX Copy]
8. **Set Permissions**

   Lastly, in order to programmatically invoke any apps on C Drive, you'll need admin privileges, so you need to open Visual Studio in Admin Mode.  You can do that by right clicking on the application like this

   [image: Run As Admin]
9. **Hit Run & Debug**

   Presto! Blamo! Your extension should now be running SSMS

   [image: SSMS Debugger]

#### Further Reading

Historically, each extension needed to be whitelisted, but according to the [release notes for SSMS 18](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#180-preview---cumulative-changelog-through-rc1), one big change (for the better) is

> Package IDs no longer needed to develop SSMS Extensions
>   In the past, SSMS was selectively loading only well-known packages, thus requiring developers to register their own package. This is no longer the case.

Since SSMS 18 uses the *Visual Studio 2017 Isolated Shell*, many of the extension developer documentation is available under the [Visual Studio Extension Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Awesome work @KyleMit - I would add that you don't need to run as admin if you give yourself Modify permissions on the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Extensions` folder

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much! I will add that if you are building the extension in VS 2019 and targeting SSMS 18, use the Nuget Package Manager to uninstall Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK 16 and instead install 15.x. Otherwise you get an error in ActivityLog.xml about not being able to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=16.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I fight couple of hours with this error. Do you know if I make it in VS19 and SSMS19 do I still need to do this trick?

Comment: Any one know or have an example on how to implement and Item menu on the Object Explorer for SSMS V18 /19?  I have been looking for a long time all I found is for  previous version of SSMS

Comment: Fwiw, the [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1377559/How-to-Create-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-18-SSMS)'s author has [his own SSMS extension on GitHub](https://github.com/Timovski/CSVPaste) in case a "real world" example is useful for next steps. For instance, he [pastes text into the active window here](https://github.com/Timovski/CSVPaste/blob/master/CSVPaste/PasteCommand/PasteCommand.cs#L95). YMMV.

Comment: Getting error while integrating with SSMS 2014-

Error: 

A call to PInvoke function 'ObjectExplorer!Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service::GetBrowserInfoInterop' has unbalanced the stack.'

Comment: @zulqadaridrishi SSMS 2014 predates support for third-party extensions - so I'm surprised the extension even loads as it won't be on the allow-list. Why are you using SSMS 2014 in 2021, out of curiosity?

Comment: I have problem with window pane for SSMS 18 using this method. Does anyone have the same issue here ?

Comment: @osynavets - you should ask a new question about that. Don't ask it in the comments here. Firstly it is entirely unclear what your problem is and secondly asking it in the comments doesn't help build a useful knowledge base of resources on this topic