# SSMS 18 VSIX project. Modify query window contents

Tags: c#, ssms, visual-studio-extensions, ssms-addin, ssms-18

Since SSMS 18 has dropped the requirements for Package IDs for SSMS Extensions I thought I'd give it a go. Being totally new in this area, I'm not sure where to start. I've gotten as far as a menu item in tools as per various tutorials out there.

What I'd like to do is modify the currently active query window to create a simple snippet auto complete feature. I.E. type 'sf'  to auto fill to 'select * from'. That kind of thing.

What references from ssms will I need to import to get started with this?

Comment: There are other Stack over flow questions similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661806/how-to-create-an-extension-for-ssms-2019-v18 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661806/how-to-create-an-extension-for-ssms-2019-v18/55661807#55661807

Comment: I should probably been more clear in the question. I've gotten that far with no issues. I specifically want to interact withe query window in SSMS