# Issue occured during extension installation for SSMS

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

i have created an extension and now i have to install it in the different targets as Visual Studio, SSMS. I have enabled the version also in install targets:

[image]

At first when i install this it is successfully installed on Visual studio and second thing it is unable to find the SSMS to install this extension.

I have gone through [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Mar/01/Registering-and-Unregistering-a-VSIX-Extension-from-the-Command-Line) article and perform the command line installation:

[image]

but no luck. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

> Issue occured during extension installation for SSMS

Actually, installing an extension in SSMS is not the same as VS IDE. I suggest you could follow these steps:

**1)** Right-click on the vsix project-->Properties-->Debug-->and then change **Start External program** into the path of SSMS installation path like this:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe`

[image]

**Besides**, under that window, you should remove the command line arguments.

[image]

**2)** create a custom folder called `VSIXProject` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Extensions`

Then, Set Deploy **VSIX** to **SSMS**:

Right-click on project-->`VSIX`-->check option `Copy VSIX content to the following location` and then input `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Extensions\VSIXProject`

[image]

**3)** Run VS as administrator and you can debug this project which debug in SSMS and when you finish debugging it. The extension will automatically installed into SSMS.

**In addition**, you can refer to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661806/how-to-create-an-extension-for-ssms-2019-v18).