# Extending a code completion (CompletionSourceProvider) for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, ssms, visual-studio-2022, vsix

Following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1377559/How-to-Create-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-18-SSMS) I was able to extend a tool menu with a command to SQL Server Management Studio 18 with Visual Studio 2022 and downgrading `Microsoft.Visual Studio.SDK` to version 15.

But the [standard sample provided by Microsoft for to display statement completion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-statement-completion?view=vs-2019&tabs=csharp) does not work. No errors in debugging and also the SSMS error log seems to have no related errors.

My code is exactly the same as the walk-through just downgraded the default SDK package to version 15 (It worked in VS2022) and changed the solution to work with SSMS, and didn't do the job there, although the command extension steal works!

Even the simpler one to [customize text view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-customizing-the-text-view?view=vs-2019&tabs=csharp) does not work either in SSMS.

I have seen samples and opensource projects that do different things in SSMS 18 but no one is about text completion. Can anyone help?